# Create array from array values

Tags: php, arrays

I have an array like this :

```
 $lessonOptions=array();
 $lessonOptions[0]=array("Physics","6.00","2015-01-01","-","4");
 $lessonOptions[1]=array("Physics","16.00","2015-01-01","-","2");
 $lessonOptions[2]=array("Maths","10.00","2015-07-01","-","10"); 
 $lessonOptions[3]=array("Maths","20.00","2015-07-01","-","10");
```

I want to create an output with new array called optionarray which contains:
**

physics 6.00  2015-01-04 -

physics 16.00 2015-01-01 -

---

maths 10.00 2015-07-01 -

maths 20.00 2015-07-07 -

My problem is that I can see every line of maths but only one line of physics is missing .
How can I display all line ?

My actual code is :

```
 $lessonGroup=$lessonOptions[0][0];
 $display=FALSE;
 $state=0;
 $nbLessons=count($lessonsOptions);

 for ($i = 0; $i<$nbLessons; $i++) 
{       
if ($i+1!=$nbLessons) $lessonGroupSuivant=$lessonOptions[$i+1][0];
else $display=TRUE;
switch ($state)
    {
    case 0 :            
        $infoLesson[$state]=$lessonOptions[$i];

    default :
        {               
        if ($lessonGroup==$lessonGroupSuivant)
            {
            $infoLesson[$state]=$lessonOptions[$i];
            $state=$state+1;
            }   
        else
            {
            $display=TRUE;
            $lessonGroup=$lessonGroupSuivant;
            $state=0;           
            }
        }
    }

if ($display==TRUE)
    {       
    //var_dump($infoLesson);

    $display=FALSE;
    }
}
```

My actual array (wrong)
As you can see, the size of my array is 1 , I need to have 2 because I have two field for the lesson physics.

```
 array(1) { [0]=> array(5) { [0]=> string(31) "physics" [1]=> string(10)      "6.00" [2]=> string(10) "2015-01-01" [3]=> string(1) "-" [4]=> float(42) } } 

 array(2) { [0]=> array(5) { [0]=> string(15) "Maths" [1]=> string(11) "10.00" [2]=> string(10) "2015-07-01" [3]=> string(1) "-" [4]=> float(10) } [1]=> array(5) { [0]=> string(15) "Maths" [1]=> string(11) "10.00" [2]=> string(10) "2015-07-12" [3]=> string(1) "-" [4]=> float(10) } }
```

Comment: What are you acually trying to achieve ?

Comment: @Djip My new array infoLesson need to have all line of lessonOptions .I am displaying all lessons separately

Comment: Pretty Unclear what you want to achieve

Comment: `My problem is that I can see every line of maths but only one line of physics is missing . How can I display all line ?` you wrote this. and my code gives answer for that

Comment: Could you maybe make a visual view of how it should be ?

Comment: @kingmaker hey, how's your progress with the issue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay i think i found what you need:

```
<?php
$lessonOptions=array();
$lessonOptions[0]=array("Physics","6.00","2015-01-01","-","4");
$lessonOptions[1]=array("Physics","16.00","2015-01-01","-","2");
$lessonOptions[2]=array("Maths","10.00","2015-07-01","-","10");
$lessonOptions[3]=array("Maths","20.00","2015-07-01","-","10");

$optionarray = array();

$lastLessonKey = '';
$i = 0;
foreach ($lessonOptions as $key => $data) {
    if (empty($lastLessonKey)) {
        $lastLessonKey = $data[0];
    } else if ($lastLessonKey !== $data[0]) {
        $i++;
        $lastLessonKey = $data[0];
    }

    $optionarray[$i][] = $data;
}

var_dump($optionarray);
```

Output:

```
array(2) { [0]=> array(2) { [0]=> array(5) { [0]=> string(7) "Physics" [1]=> string(4) "6.00" [2]=> string(10) "2015-01-01" [3]=> string(1) "-" [4]=> string(1) "4" } [1]=> array(5) { [0]=> string(7) "Physics" [1]=> string(5) "16.00" [2]=> string(10) "2015-01-01" [3]=> string(1) "-" [4]=> string(1) "2" } } [1]=> array(2) { [0]=> array(5) { [0]=> string(5) "Maths" [1]=> string(5) "10.00" [2]=> string(10) "2015-07-01" [3]=> string(1) "-" [4]=> string(2) "10" } [1]=> array(5) { [0]=> string(5) "Maths" [1]=> string(5) "20.00" [2]=> string(10) "2015-07-01" [3]=> string(1) "-" [4]=> string(2) "10" } } }
```

Comment: Yes I want an array output like this . I think There is a little mistake on your array format.Missing array ?

Comment: What do you mean by missing array? Do you want physics and maths to be 2 separate arrays? If so then I can easy tweak the code.

Comment: No because after I will display $infoLesson in my pdf .I am 80% to finalize but missing one element in my code , if you can check my code.

Comment: What's the problem with the code I made then? Explain please

Comment: It wont work if arrays are not lined up like that perfectly. Try adding $lessonOptions[5]=array("Physics","11.00","2015-01-01","-","2") and then running the code. It will end up with 3 result arrays.

Comment: It's not complete for display in one variable .You array have a wrong structure

Comment: @JungleZombie i know, I didn't take that in account.

Comment: @kingmaker so you want all the data in the first array to be merged an put like I did?

Comment: @kingmaker You want it like this? array(2) { [0]=> array(2) { [0]=> string(27) "Physics 6.00 2015-01-01 - 4" [1]=> string(28) "Physics 16.00 2015-01-01 - 2" } [1]=> array(2) { [0]=> string(27) "Maths 10.00 2015-07-01 - 10" [1]=> string(27) "Maths 20.00 2015-07-01 - 10" } }

Answer (score 0):

So, you are willing to group arrays by some value

```
$infoLesson = array();

foreach ($lessonOptions as $v) {
   $infoLesson[$v[0]][] = $v; 
}
```

You can then retrieve arrays by key. 
For example printing **$infoLesson['Maths']** will get you

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [0] => Maths
            [1] => 10.00
            [2] => 2015-07-01
            [3] => -
            [4] => 10
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [0] => Maths
            [1] => 20.00
            [2] => 2015-07-01
            [3] => -
            [4] => 10
        )

)
```

And **$infoLesson['Physics']**

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [0] => Physics
            [1] => 6.00
            [2] => 2015-01-01
            [3] => -
            [4] => 4
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [0] => Physics
            [1] => 16.00
            [2] => 2015-01-01
            [3] => -
            [4] => 2
        )

)
```

Comment: Yea I need to group It and display within one and one variable.Here my variable is $infoLesson.